# How can I get Jacoco coverage Report per Request

Tags: java, rest, runtime, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using `jacoco` agent to generate my [coverage reports](https://dzone.com/articles/code-coverage-report-generator-for-java-projects-a) in the form of `xml` files by running the command:

```
java -jar <path>/sample_projects/beta/jacoco-code-coverage/jacoco-code-coverage-example/src/main/resources/lib/jacococli.jar report <path>/sample_projects/beta/jacoco-code-coverage/jacoco-code-coverage-example/target/jacoco-it.exec --classfiles <path>/sample_projects/beta/jacoco-code-coverage/jacoco-code-coverage-example/target/classes/com --sourcefiles src/main/java/ --xml <path>/sample_projects/beta/jacoco-code-coverage/jacoco-code-coverage-example/target/report.xml
```

This basically writes to `jacoco-it.exec` file and it saves previous coverage data as well.
But I want coverage analysis per request made, is there any way I can erase previous data collected by jacoco agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I got the solution just reset the exec dump at my middleware after the request has been made in this order I am able to get the coverage analysis per request.

```
 ExecDumpClient execDumpClient = new ExecDumpClient();
        execDumpClient.setReset(true);
        execDumpClient.dump("localhost", 36320);
```